# What's the best the approach to add an extra attribute field in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I'm using Drupal Commerce and i have a product type called "Painting" this product type does not have an attribute fields, I'm using inline_entity_form module so i can show the product add form within the node add form for my product display content type.

The product in the site is the painting itself, it may come with a frame or without a frame (the user can choose) and the price will change based on the user's choice, **how can i add such field without using attributes fields?** as attributes fields requires that the site admin to add many products and put them in one product display, i just want to keep it simple to the site admin, to make him add the product in the same way he adds a node.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you just need two variations:

- Product one, without frame
- Product two, with frame

Each variation has it's own price and title.

You can get by without using an attribute field. Drupal Commerce renders a dropdown when there are no attributes and allows user's to pick from the product variation titles. Since you are using Inline Entity Form this should be seamless for the site admin.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Is this approach valid for commerce 2?

Comment: Yes. We have the variation title widget you can use for your add to cart form. Turn off title generation for your variation.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. I can only get this to work by creating a seperate order item type and specifying 'Product variation title' for the purchased entity. This seems an abstract way of going about things and quite probabley wrong. Please see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/249969/how-to-display-selectable-variations-without-attributes